# "A rose by any other name would smell as sweet" but with a more negative connotation

Tags: phrases, idioms, metaphors

"A rose by any other name would smell as sweet" is from Shakespeare's Romeo and Juliet. It means: what matters is what something *is*, not what it's called.

I feel like this phrase has a very positive connotation to it: what matter is not what this **fantastic** thing is called, it matters what it is. Is there another common phrase, metaphor, or idiom I can use that has a more negative connotation? I'm looking for a phrase that says that it doesn't matter what this **bad** thing is called, it's still the same bad thing.

An idiom like, "lipstick on a pig" or "sugarcoating" means making a bad thing seem less bad. This is **not** what I'm trying to convey.

Comment: As an aside, while Googling this phrase I learned that Juliet says this to Romeo to say "you're still a Montague!" (which to her is bad). But a Rose is such a beautiful thing? Maybe there's another metaphor about thorns on a rose? I don't know :)

Comment: You mean something like "You can call a concentration camp a 'summer camp,' but it still has barbed wire, armed guards, and no privacy"?

Comment: “A durian by any other name would still stink the place up something rotten”?

Comment: [Nice legs shame about the face](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kf44LWY7cdQ) Not quite there, but it does carry negative connotations!

Answer (score 2):

**A pig by any other name**

[still smells](https://www.farmanddairy.com/columns/a-pig-by-any-other-name-still-smells/6503.html)

[again](http://www.londonderrynh.net/2015/12/a-pig-by-any-other-name%E2%80%A6-again/83620)

[is zebra](https://www.lostateminor.com/2009/11/05/zebra-pig/)

[would smell as sweet](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/auntwztn/a-pig-by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet/)

Comment: "A pig by any other name is zebra" is NOT a common idiom and for non-native speakers a misleading answer.

Comment: "A Pig By Any Other Name… (Again)" You forgot to add the ellipses and the brackets, hints at the original idiom but would not work in speech and would only confuse the listener. Nice website though.

Comment: No rich man ever succeeds in disguising himself as a poor man; for money, like murder, will out.  -George Orwell